# How to generate a blank crossword sheet?

Tags: algorithm

I attempted to generate a blank crossword sheet. My method is by combining the rows and columns as shown on the graph below. However, some of the `across` and `down` numbers then appeared out of place after combining. What is the better way to obtain a blank crossword sheet?

[image]

```
fillRow[i_] := (
   startPos = RandomInteger[{1, randomStartPos}] ;
   randomWordLen = RandomInteger[{minWordLen, dimX - startPos}];
   endPos = startPos + randomWordLen - 1;
   Do[cwSheet[[i, n]] = 0, {n, startPos, endPos}];
   AppendTo[ hintNumPad, { counter++, {startPos, dimX - i}}]
    If[endPos <= dimX/2,
     randomWordLen = RandomInteger[{minWordLen, dimX - endPos - 1}];
     Do[cwSheet[[i, n]] = 0, {n, dimX, dimX - randomWordLen + 1, -1}];
     AppendTo[ 
      hintNumPad, { counter++, {dimX - randomWordLen + 1, dimX - i}}];
     ]
   );


fillCol[j_] := (
   startPos = RandomInteger[{1, randomStartPos}] ;
   randomWordLen = RandomInteger[{minWordLen, dimY - startPos}];
   endPos = startPos + randomWordLen - 1;
   Do[cwSheet[[   n , j]] = 0, {n, startPos, endPos}];
   AppendTo[ hintNumPad, { counter++, { j, dimY - startPos  }}]
     If[endPos <= dimX/2,
     randomWordLen = RandomInteger[{minWordLen, dimX - endPos - 1}];
     Do[cwSheet[[n, j]] = 0, {n, dimY, dimY - randomWordLen + 1, -1}];
     AppendTo[ hintNumPad, { counter++, {j, randomWordLen - 1  }}];
     ] 
   );

minWordLen = 3;
hintNumPad = {};
{dimX, dimY} = {9, 9};
randomStartPos = 4;
Clear[cwSheet];

cwSheet = ConstantArray[1, {dimX, dimY}];

 counter = 1;
 Do[fillRow[k], {k, 1, dimY, 2}]; 

 counter = 1;
 Do[fillCol[k], {k, 1, dimX, 2}]; 


g = MatrixPlot[cwSheet , Mesh -> All,
  Frame -> False,
  ColorFunction -> "Monochrome", 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style[#[[1]], 9], #[[2]] + {-0.9, 0.8}] & /@ 
     hintNumPad}]
```

The correct positions of the hint numbers should look like this:

[image]

Comment: They look in-place to me, given the original rows and columns; seems like you need to tweak the algorithm that generates the original rows and columns themselves.

Comment: It looks entirely wrong to me, even after the movements of numbers indicated in your final drawing.  In crosswords I am familiar with (UK, occasionally US) there would be a 2 where you have 4 in the first row, a 3 where you have 2 in the first column, 4 where you have 2 in the third column, etc.  Perhaps number the solution spaces after assembling the grid ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One can use `CellularAutomaton` and apply only one rule: do not allow 4 white cells together!

```
ClearAll[f];
f@{{1, 1, _}, {1, _, _}, {_, _, _}} = 0;
f@{{_, 1, 1}, {_, _, 1}, {_, _, _}} = 0;
f@{{_, _, _}, {_, _, 1}, {_, 1, 1}} = 0;
f@{{_, _, _}, {1, _, _}, {1, 1, _}} = 0;
f@{_, {_, x_, _}, _} := If[Random[] < 0.1, 1, x];
```

Here `0` and `1` mark black and white cells respectively.
These rules are so simple so we have to introduce an enhancement: delete words of length 2 and select large morphological components.

```
del = # //. {x___, 0, 1, 1, 0, z___} :> {x, 0, 0, 0, 0, z} &;

ca = Unitize@SelectComponents[#, Large] &@
          MorphologicalComponents[#, CornerNeighbors -> False] &@
        ArrayPad[#, -1] &@del@Transpose@del@ArrayPad[#, 1] &@
    CellularAutomaton[{f[#] &, {}, {1, 1}}, #, {{200}}][[1]] &;
```

Now we can apply `ca` several times to obtain better result

```
res = Nest[ca, ConstantArray[0, {12, 12}], 4];
```

It remains to find labels and show the result

```
labels = Position[#, {_, {0, 1, 1}, _} | {{_, 0, _}, {_, 1, _}, {_, 1, _}},
    {2}] &@Partition[#, {3, 3}, 1] &@ ArrayPad[res, 1];

ArrayPlot[1 - res, Mesh -> All, Frame -> False, MeshStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 9], 
   {#[[2]] - 0.95, Length@res - #[[1]] + 0.95}, {-1, 1}] &, labels]]
```

[image]

P.S. There is a small probability to obtain incorrect field.

---

`CellularAutomaton` apply rules with periodic boundary conditions. One can treat it as the torus topology of the crossword ([code](http://pastebin.com/sk98c1ms)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. To tell the true, looking at your code, Mathematica suddenly became a complete foreign language
to me! :)

Comment: @Putterboy It was the same for me two years ago. There is a nice guide: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs
   mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/193).

Comment: @ybeltukov +1 thanks for a this very instructive post and creative use of cellular automata, particularly nice to have random component and constraint word length > 2.

Answer (score 9):

**By Using `HitMissTransform[]` to detect "words" of length > 1**

```
(*Generate a symmetric Puzzle**)
n = 15;
f = Unitize@(# + Transpose@#) &;
i = f@BlockRandom[RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {n, n}]];

(*Calculate*)
k = {{-1, 1, 1}};
p = Position[f@ImageData@HitMissTransform[Image@i, k, Padding -> 0], 1];

(* Print *)
ArrayPlot[i - 1, Mesh -> All, 
  Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]],#1] &, SortBy[p/.{a_,b_}:>{b -.8, n-a +.8}, -#[[2]] &]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 *Mathematica* has function for everything :)

Answer (score 4):

The following generates square crosswords. It has a number of limitations.

```
cw[rv_] :=
 Module[{lg, sa, val, a, d, i, sel, text},
  lg = Length[rv[[1]]];
  sa = SparseArray[rv];
  val = Complement[Tuples[Range[lg], 2], sa["NonzeroPositions"]];
  a[list_, x_] := And[Not[MemberQ[list, x + {0, -1}]],
    MemberQ[list, x + {0, 1}]
    ];
  d[list_, x_] := 
   And[Not[MemberQ[list, x + {-1, 0}]], MemberQ[list, x + {1, 0}]];
  i[list_, x_] := 
   And @@ (Not@MemberQ[list, x + #] & /@ {{-1, 0}, {1, 
        0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}});
  sel = Select[val, Or[a[val, #], d[val, #], i[val, #]] &];
  text = MapIndexed[
    Text[First@#2, {Last@#1, lg - First@#1} - {0.8, -0.8}] &, sel];
  ArrayPlot[rv, Mesh -> All, Epilog -> text]]
```

Examples:

```
anim = cw[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.4], #]] & /@ {{4, 
     4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}};
```

[image]

or static version:

[image]

If you happened to have your square crossword, e.g. this rather uninspiring one:

```
mat = {{0, "C", "R", "O", "S", "S", 0},
   {0, "A", 0, 0, "E", 0, "H"},
   {0, "N", "O", "T", "E", 0, "E"},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "L"},
   {"T", "O", "E", 0, "H", "O", "P"},
   {"A", 0, "R", 0, "A", 0, "S"},
   {"P", "L", "A", "N", "T", 0, 0}
   };
cw[mat /. {_String :> 0, 0 -> 1}]
Show[cw[mat /. {_String :> 0, 0 -> 1}], 
 Graphics@Text[
     Style[Extract[mat, #], Red, 
      20], {Last@#, 7 - First@#} + {-0.5, 0.5}] & /@ (SparseArray[
     mat]["NonzeroPositions"])]
```

[image]